# Where's a good spot to get Rainbow Coins in Rainbow Moon early on?

Tags: rainbow-moon

I've been playing Rainbow Moon on Hard/Adventuresome, and just got the bonus 750 rainbow coins for the latter, but there's a lot of expensive scrolls I want to buy.  Is there a spot fairly early on where you can farm coins pretty well?

Side note, there's a free Add-On on PSN for 100 coins and 50 pearls for Baldren, which is a welcome help on hard mode.  I'm perfectly willing to fork over another $2 for this awesome game, but I feel like I'm cheating if I buy an add on for gold/pearls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early in the game,

- Make sure you're getting the hidden **?** points. Many of these have a dozen coins in them, and they seem to be about twice as common as bags.
- Explore whole dungeons. Every dungeon I've done so far has had some optional / hidden parts which contained a fair number of coins.
- The well on East Caesar Island has a secret passage.
- The well near Orad has about 50 coins every Moon day. (Not the well *in* Orad, but the next village over. It's next to what was probably the first tavern you found.)
- Sell your materials! A lot of the materials are worth a decent amount of money and have little or no effect when crafting.
- [Bags dropped in combat contain more items if you get them *during* combat instead of after.](http://www.eastasiasoft.com/index.php/forum/11-rainbow-moon/2653-bags-in-combat#2655)
- This is pretty minuscule, but some containers will refresh if you cancel out and reopen them. So you might open it once and find 2 coins, then cancel and reopen and find 8.

Luck does *not* affect drop rates, contrary to some guesses on the Internet.

Personally the number of scrolls is outpacing my ability to buy them, but it's also outpacing my ability to equip new skills, so I've not felt a need to save up for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you only get coins from chests and monster drops I can't really think of a good place early on. The best way but obviously the most annoying is to fight random encounters. If you can find an enemy that drops "valuable materials" eg. Living shards. You can sell those for a decent profit